# How to run a command in Bash at the next 10 second boundary?

Tags: bash, cron

I want to run a command at the next 10 second boundary (e.g. `mpstat -u 10`). That is, I want the command to start at the 0, 10, 20, ... or the 50th second. This will basically avoid [RRDtool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) that I use to generate graphs and that expects data at specific times, from interpolating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with something that seems to work!

```
diff=$((10 - $(date '+%s') % 10)); sleep $diff; mpstat -u 10
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution waits in every loop until seconds of current minute is one of {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50} and then executes a command (date in my example). If execution of the command takes more than 10 seconds an execution is skipped.

```
while true ; do 
  sleep $((10 - `date +%S` % 10)); 
  date; #or any other command
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use sleep 10 for every "loop" you want. so if it would be in a loop it would seem like that, so it will run what you want every 10 sec.

```
while sth.true
do
       do.sth
       sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this odd solution:

```
$  let sec=(10 - $(date "+%S") % 10 ) ; sleep $sec ; mpstat -u 10
Linux 3.16.0-62-generic (Tetrapharmakon)    04/13/16    _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

12:11:40     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
12:11:50     all    0.89    0.01    0.43    0.09    0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.57
```

### ----

The first not accurate enough solution for history.

Make the cron daemon starts a custom script each minute:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * /tmp/myscript.sh >> /tmp/date.output
```

The script runs the command every 10 second exactly:

```
#!/bin/bash --
for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6; do
  date
  sleep 10
done
```

Comment: This is not going to be exact when the `date` command takes time.

Comment: @Benhard true! then, accept the pdp's answer if this is a viable solution for you.

Comment: Yeah, it is not my question ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Bash built-in `SECONDS` variable is useful for this:

```
while : ; do
    sleep $(( 10 - SECONDS%10 ))
    mpstat -u 10
done
```

Comment: Interesting. However, note that `SECONDS` stores the number of seconds since the shell was invoked. It does not have any relation to system time.